# C# listview datapager

Tags: c#, listview, datapager

Im have searched but i can´t find a way of giving a ButtonCount

NumericPagerField ButtonCount="2"  -> dynamically

Anyone?

Comment: Is this WPF, Silverlight or Winforms?

Comment: Ciao Pedro can you rephrase your question? it's not very clear, anyone what?